# Quasy - modal component does not hide itself

Tags: block-editor

I have this component, it is supposed to work as some sort of extra-entering-dialog.
It is imported in Edit function of the block.

```
/**
 * Component for entering biography
 */

import { InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { Button } from '@wordpress/components';
import { useState } from '@wordpress/element';



const BiographyModal = ({ name }) => {
    const [ isOpen, setIsOpen ] = useState(false);
    const modal =
        <div className="biography-modal">
            <h3>{ `Životopis ${ name }` }</h3>
            <InnerBlocks />
            <Button isDefault onClick={ () => setIsOpen({ isOpen: false }) }>
                Završi uređivanje
            </Button>
        </div>;

    return (
        <div>
            <Button isDefault onClick={ () => setIsOpen({ isOpen: true }) }>Uredi životopis</Button>
            { isOpen && modal }
        </div>
    )
}

export default BiographyModal;
```

It does open on button lower in code, but it does not close when clicking on button higher in code. It won't even close when I change state of isOpen by using React developer tools in browser. At first I thought this was because dismounting of InnerBlocks or Button is not allowed, but after I remove those two (and give lower button possibility to function as toggle button (`setIsOpen({ isOpen: ! isOpen })`), this still does not close. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `setIsOpen()` incorrectly.

Your code initialises `isOpen` as `false`, and your code implies that it can be either `true` or `false`, but that's not what you're setting it as. The `setIsOpen()` function updates `isOpen` to the value you pass to it, and you're passing an object with an `isOpen` property, not a boolean value.

When you call `setIsOpen({ isOpen: false })`, you're not setting `isOpen` to `false`, you're setting it to `{ isOpen: false }`. You need to just pass `true` or `false`:

```
<Button isDefault onClick={ () => setIsOpen(false) }>
```

Note that this is React functionality, not anything to do with WordPress, so you should review the documentation for [`useState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: Yes, I was to much used to setAttribute syntax to notice the error.